# How do I echo an image multiple times?

Tags: php, image

I am trying to make a web page that echoes images depending on how many visitors its had. The code I have so far counts the visits to the page and stores the number in a variable `$count`. I then echo a random image on the page `$image`. Now I want to multiply the random image displayed on the page by the amount of visits `$count`. So that if there has been 20 visits, 20 random images will be echoed on the page. Any ideas how to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
$fp = fopen("count.txt", "r");
$count = fread($fp, 1024);
fclose($fp);
$count = $count + 1; 

$random = rand(0, 30);

$image = "<img src='" . $random . ".jpg'/>";

echo $image;

$fp = fopen("count.txt", "w");

fwrite($fp, $count);
fclose($fp);
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like a homework. voting to close

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you're looking for.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $random = rand(0, 30);
    $image = "<img src='" . $random . ".jpg'/>";
    echo $image;
}
```

You need to regenerate the random number each time through the loop, otherwise you'll get the same image repeated multiple times. Now, if you want to make sure you get unique random images, that's a bit more complicated!

**-- edit**

To get unique random images, the method I've generally used is to add each random ID to an array inside the loop, and check that each time. Something like this (inserted just after the `$random = rand(0,30);` line):

```
while(in_array($random, $random_used)) {
  $random = rand(0, 30);
}
$random_used[] = $random;
```

To be clear about the limitations of this - if you have a count higher than the random range in use, you're going to hit an infinite loop here. Also, you should initialise the array (outside of your for-loop), such as:

```
$random_used = array();
```

...just to stop PHP notices.

There's probably a simpler way to do this, but this is the method I've generally used.

Comment: Thank for your answer, very helpful :) out of interest, do you know what the best way to get unique random images would be?

Comment: I've expanded the answer to respond to that.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as :

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    $random = rand(0, 30);
    echo '<img src="'. $random . '.jpg"/>';
}
```

Comment: See my explanation in my answer. This will show the same image each time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
{
  $random = rand(0, 30);

  $image = "<img src='" . $random . ".jpg'/>";

  echo $image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) {
   $random = rand(0, 30);
   $image = "<img src='" . $random . ".jpg'/>";
   echo $image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$count` is the number of visits. Do semething like this:

```
$count = 20; // I suppose that there are 20 visitors
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $random = rand(0, 30);
    $image = "<img src='" . $random . ".jpg'/>";
    echo $image;
}
```

Output the image and define a random number in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use old file handling stuff.

```
$count = file_get_contents("count.txt") + 1;

$a = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    $random = rand(0, 30);

    while (in_array($random, $a) && count($a) <= 30) {
        $random = rand(0, 30);
    }

    array_push($a, $random);

    $image = "<img src='" . $random . ".jpg'/>";

    echo $image;

}

file_put_contents("count.txt", $count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$images = range(0, 12);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    // you shoulod check whether count is not above the number of available images
    $image = array_rand($images, 1);

    echo "<img src='" . $images[$image] . ".jpg'/>";

    unset($images);
}
```

Using the above you will get unique images only